# no quiero recibir notificaciones (FCM) cuando mato la aplicación. Swift

Tags: swift, push-notification, firebase-messaging

tengo el problema de que no quiero recibir notificaciones cuando mi app en swift esta cerrada(matada) mis notificaciones llegan en primer y segundo plano pero no quiero recibirlas cuando mato la app. esta es mi cara util y mi código.

```
{

    "to": "e32toasdauVC7OUz8z",
        "content-available":true,

        "notification": {
             "sound" : " ",
            "mutable_content": true
        },

        "data": {
            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/Coiled_Galaxy.jpg",
            "title": "title",
            "body": "****body****.",
            "mutable_content": true

        }

    }



@available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
                switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState
                    {
                    case .active:
                        completionHandler( [.alert,.sound])
                        break
                    default:
                        completionHandler( [.alert,.sound])
                        break
                          }
                             }
        }   
  }
```

Comment: Eliminando el completion handler en el caso default?

Comment: no, por que cuando una aplicación se mata ya no llama a nada del código sino que manda las notificaciones al dispositivo directamente.